# Почему-то tr располагает элементы по вертикали вместо стандартного поведения по горизонтали

Tags: javascript, html, css

***Добрый день, tr в таблице почему-то начал располагать ячейки по вертикали,*** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Стили tr и table -***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это стандартное поведение `<tr>`... Попробуйте `<td>`.

Comment: Что? tr по умолчанию всегда по горизонтали выстраивает клеточки, td же это вроде как тег для ячейки

Comment: TR - Table Row (табличная строка).

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, но к чему это? скажите лучше если знаете почему оно так ведет себя, и как это исправить

Comment: Html код можно, того что не работает?

Comment: Я не знаю что и как вы сверстали, и что именно хотите получить от верстки. Я могу лишь сказать, что тэг `<tr>` в вашем случает работает абсолютно правильно. Он будет выстраивать данные внутри себя строками - по одной `<tr>` на каждую строку таблицы.

Comment: Td -  блок,  tr  - елемент - линия для блока который ещё и жадный

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В итоге решил проблему тем, что начал разбирать прям по тегам весь код, и в итоге проблема была в том, что в классе ячейки (td) был display flex. Я убрал и всё стало на место.

Comment: `flex` конечно не `table-cell`, но оно бы скорее всего сделало бы что они отображались в одну строку. Обычно, когда устанавливаю `flex`, элементы выстраиваются в строку.

Comment: Да, но есть же ещё наследование, и видимо оно отнаследовало направление в виду колонки

Answer (score -1):

```css
td,th { text-align: right; width: 2rem; }
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <caption>Таблица умножения</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th>
    <th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th><th>9</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
    <td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2</th><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>6</td><td>8</td>
    <td>10</td><td>12</td><td>14</td><td>16</td><td>18</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>3</th><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>9</td><td>12</td>
    <td>15</td><td>18</td><td>21</td><td>24</td><td>27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>4</th><td>4</td><td>8</td><td>12</td><td>16</td>
    <td>20</td><td>24</td><td>28</td><td>32</td><td>36</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>5</th><td>5</td><td>10</td><td>15</td><td>20</td>
    <td>25</td><td>30</td><td>35</td><td>40</td><td>45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>6</th><td>6</td><td>12</td><td>18</td><td>24</td>
    <td>30</td><td>36</td><td>42</td><td>48</td><td>54</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>7</th><td>7</td><td>14</td><td>21</td><td>28</td>
    <td>35</td><td>42</td><td>49</td><td>56</td><td>63</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>8</th><td>8</td><td>16</td><td>24</td><td>32</td>
    <td>40</td><td>48</td><td>56</td><td>64</td><td>72</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>9</th><td>9</td><td>18</td><td>27</td><td>36</td>
    <td>45</td><td>54</td><td>63</td><td>72</td><td>81</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Это вообще не то... Может есть какой-то стиль который делает tr в столбик, ибо я подключаю кучу либ, может быть одна из них касается table в глобальном смысле

Comment: Вот поэтому нужно добавлять код для воспроизведения ошибки в вопрос.